# Why isn't the default bootstrap template working for me?

Tags: bootstrapping

I don't know what's going on. For the past few hours, I've been trying to get Bootstrap to work, and I can't do it. It worked fine on FreeCodeCamp, but despite me copying the template code from the Bootstrap website, it will not work. I've tried opening the file in both Firefox and Chrome. First I tried only using their template in Sublime, then I added the container div to see if it would center the text (it didn't).

Their Template: [I've copied the code into Sublime and it's still not working](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Comment: Have you copied css/ and js/ files that included from the template?

Comment: I copied absolutely everything in their template

Comment: Make sure you have included all required CSS and js file into your project and into head section of your page. you may need to download files and include them into your project. if it does not work, open developer option of browser and check for errors in it.

Comment: Just to be sure: you have 3 files now: index.html, css/bootstrap.min.css and js/bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: I just now renamed the files because you can't save that slash in windows, but yes, I do have them. I know it's against the etiquette here, but I took a screenshot for proof. http://imgur.com/a/jNSy6

Comment: I fixed it. They actually didn't include a link to bootstrap in their template